# Avoiding widow/orphan lines with parcolumns

Tags: widows-orphans, parcolumns

I am using `parcolumns` for two parallel columns, and I have also set

```
\widowpenalty=10000         % avoid widows
\clubpenalty=10000          % avoid orphans
```

But while `\widowpenalty` and `\clubpenalty` work well for default environments, I find I am getting widow/orphan lines within the `parcolumns` environment. Is there a setting to avoid that?

Comment: You could switch to paracol (MikTeX no long even carries parcolumns).  Otherwise, \raggedbottom? \parskip=0pt plus 1fil?

Comment: Thanks. `paracol` seems the best choice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.